# Event binding not working in telerik windows controls for universal apps

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, telerik, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn Micro MVVM framework for my universal app with Telerik's controls for Universal apps. But default (for framework) event binding feature not work with event RadAutoCompleteBox.SelectionChanged. If I add

```
micro:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action ChangeCurrency()]"
```

into my XAML code

```
_navigationService.UriFor<MyViewModel>().Navigate();
```

not work (navigation not occured without any errors). And when I remove that line - all works good.

My view:

```
<telerikUniversalInput:RadAutoCompleteBox
  ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}"
  micro:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action ChangeCurrency()]"
  Text="{Binding Account, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  IsTextMatchHighlightEnabled="True"
  AutosuggestFirstItem="True"
  FilterComparisonMode="CurrentCultureIgnoreCase"
  FilterMode="Contains"
  Header="Accounts">
  <telerikUniversalInput:RadAutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock 
          Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </telerikUniversalInput:RadAutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>         
</telerikUniversalInput:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: <TextBlock 
          Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </TextBlock>
I assume this is suppose to be a TextBox?

Comment: try using _navigationService.NavigateToViewModel() see if it works. There is a generic form as well...